# Python regex: match only if pattern is repeated n number of times

Tags: python, regex

I have a string: `Name  Mass  From  To  Disulphide bond  -2.02  97  144  Disulphide bond  -2.02  111  158  Disulphide bond  -2.02  121  174  Disulphide bond  -2.02  125  176  Disulphide bond  -2.02  85  174  Disulphide bond  -2.02  10  176`

I want to pull out the tuples (97,144), (111,158), (121,174),(125,176), (85,174), (10,176) (i.e. the pairs of numbers after -2.02 in each case).

I only want to match the strings that match this exact number of repeated patterns (i.e. where the same word pattern of 'Disulphide bond -2.02 X X' is repeated exactly 6 times). There will be other strings in the file with the exact same pattern, but repeated more or less times than 6 times (e.g. another string in the file might be `'Name  Mass  From  To  Disulphide bond  -2.02  97  144  Disulphide bond  -2.02  111  158  Disulphide bond  -2.02  121  174'`, I do not want to match this).

I was originally writing a regex like this:

```
six_regex = re.search(r'Name  Mass  From  To  Disulphide bond  -2.02  ([\d]+)  ([\d]+)  Disulphide bond  -2.02  ([\d]+)  ([\d]+)  Disulphide bond  -2.02  ([\d]+)  ([\d]+)  Disulphide bond  -2.02  ([\d]+)  ([\d]+)  Disulphide bond  -2.02  ([\d]+)  ([\d]+)  Disulphide bond  -2.02  ([\d]+)  ([\d]+)',mod_line)
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to just write a regex like:

```
ix_regex = re.search(r' Disulphide bond  -2.02  ([\d]+)  ([\d]+)  ',mod_line)
```

where I add in 'match only if the above phrase is matched 6 times'.

I was using regex101.com to work with something like `Disulphide bond  -2.02  ([\d]+)  ([\d\s]+){6}` because I read elsewhere on stackoverflow that putting the number in parenthesis might be a solution; but i seem to get no matches.

Can someone advise on a neater regex, where I need to match a repeating pattern n times for it to be a match.

Comment: Do you mean there must be 6 *consecutive* `Disulphide bond X X X` or can the matches appear anywhere in the string? Please check [this approach](https://ideone.com/W0pYJc) in case they may appear anywhere in the string.

Comment: try `Name  Mass  From  To  (?:Disulphide bond  -2.02  ([\d]+)  ([\d]+)){6}`

Comment: Also see  https://ideone.com/P32pbg if they must be consecutive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this code in python:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Name  Mass  From  To  Disulphide bond  -2.02  97  144  Disulphide bond  -2.02  111  158  Disulphide bond  -2.02  121  174  Disulphide bond  -2.02  125  176  Disulphide bond  -2.02  85  174  Disulphide bond  -2.02  10  176'
>>> arr = re.findall(r'(?<=Disulphide bond  -2.02  )(\d+)  (\d+)', s)
>>> if len(arr) == 6:
...     print arr
...
[('97', '144'), ('111', '158'), ('121', '174'), ('125', '176'), ('85', '174'), ('10', '176')]
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/x7DHLg)

**RegEx Details:&&

- `(?<=Disulphide bond  -2.02  )`: Lookbehind expression to assert that we have given string on the left of current position
- `(\d+)  (\d+)`: Match 2 numbers separated by 2 spaces in 2 different capture groups

Comment: This assumes the matches can appear anywhere in the string, just like [I suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55687552/python-regex-match-only-if-pattern-is-repeated-n-number-of-times#comment98058341_55687552)

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea with the `{6}` quantifier.

Your problem is not grouping (`(?:)` - non selecting group) the right pattern.

`Name Mass From To (?:Disulphide bond -2\.02 ([\d]+) ([\d]+)\s*){6}` should do the trick.

### Explanation

- `Name  Mass  From  To` - the beginning of the string.
- `(?:` - open of non selecting group.
- `Disulphide bond -2\.02 ([\d]+) ([\d]+)\s*` - the pattern you want repeated
- `)` - close the non selecting group.
- `{6}` - repeat the non selecting group six times.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you can use

```py
reg1 = re.compile(r"(?:\s?Disulphide bond  -2.02  [\d]+  [\d]+\s?){6}")
matches = reg1.findall(your_string)

reg2 = re.compile(r"Disulphide bond  -2.02  ([\d]+)  ([\d]+)")
pairs = [reg2.findall(el) for el in matches]
```

first you match all the instances where this motif is repeated exactly six times then your extract the pairs from each instance